# Java regex to match curly braces - "invalid escape sequence"

Tags: java, regex

I want to parse nested JSON strings by splitting them up recursively by { }. The regex I came up with is "{([^}]*.?)}", which I've [tested](http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/) appropriately grabs the string I want. However, when I try to include it in my Java I get the following error: "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \ )"

This is my code, and where the error occurs:

```
String[] strArr = jsonText.split("\{([^}]*.?)\}");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't escape the curly braces...

Comment: Use double back slashes to escape backslash for Java itself first. Next you don't need to escape curly braces.

Comment: BTW, there are good libraries on the Web to parse JSON for Java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Comment: `.` is redundant..no need of it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<s>1. Curle braces have no special meaning here for regexp language, so they should not be escaped I think.</s>

2. If you want to escape them, you can. Backslash is an escape symbol for regexp, but it also should be escaped for Java itself with second backslash.
3. There are good JSON parsing libraries https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library
4. You are using reluctant quantifier, so it won't work with nested braces, for example for `{"a", {"b", "c"}, "d"}` it will match `{"a", {"b", "c"}`

Comment: Just a little remark: curly braces actually have special meaning for regex engine (e.g. A{1,2} for A and AA). Unescaped, they may cause weird erros, while `Pattern.compile(...)`.

Comment: **curly braces have meaning in regular expressions**, they can be used to say **how many time a repetition can occur**. eg. [A-Z]{1,4} means upper case letters will occur between between 1 and 4 times.

Comment: Just so you know, that question you linked has been removed (I suspect because it was a request for a library).

Comment: If first curly brace is a first symbol in regexp, it **really** means nothing for regexp language, so it **should not** be escaped.

Answer (score 23):

The nasty thing about Java regexes is that java doesn't recognize a regex as a regex.
It accepts only `\\`, `\'`, `\"` or `\u[hexadecimal number]` as valid escape sequences. 
You'll thus have to escape the backslashes because obviously `\{` is an invalid escape sequence.
Corrected version:

```
String[] strArr = jsonText.split("\\{([^}]*.?)\\}");
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape your backslash with one more backslash. Since, `\{` is not a valid escape sequence: -

```
String[] strArr = jsonText.split("\\{([^\\}]*.?)\\}");
```

You can refer to [Pattern documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more information about escape sequences.

Answer (score 4):

The regular expression should be

```
"\\{([^}]*?)\\}"
```

`.` is not required!

Answer (score 3):

Double the backslashes:

```
String[] strArr = jsonText.split("\\{([^}]*.?)\\}");
```