# Remove curly brace in Java

Tags: java

I have a text file in which each line begins and ends with a curly brace:

```
{aaa,":"bbb,ID":"ccc,}  
{zzz,":"sss,ID":"fff,}  
{ggg,":"hhh,ID":"kkk,} ...
```

Between the characters there are no spaces. I'm trying to remove the curly braces and replace them with white space as follows:

```
String s = "{aaa,":"bbb,ID":"ccc,}";
String n = s.replaceAll("{", " ");
```

I've tried escaping the curly brace using:

```
String n = s.replaceAll("/{", " "); 
String n = s.replaceAll("'{'", " ");
```

None of this works, as it comes up with an error. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Just as a note the / doesn't escape the character.. \ does

Comment: Are you getting a `Pattern Syntax Exception`, or is it just doing nothing? Also, as @RyanHurling said, you need to use `\\` to escape. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the post it is  /

Answer (score 23):

you cannot define a String like this:

```
String s = "{aaa,":"bbb,ID":"ccc,}";
```

The error is here, you have to escape the double quotes inside the string, like this:

```
String s = "{aaa,\":\"bbb,ID\":\"ccc,}";
```

Now there will be no error if you call

```
s.replaceAll("\\{", " ");
```

If you have an IDE (that is a program like eclipse), you will notice that a string is colored different from the standard color black (for example the color of a method or a semicolon [;]). If the string is all of the same color (usually brown, sometimes blue) then you should be ok, if you notice some black color inside, you are doing something wrong. Usually the only thing that you would put after a double quote ["] is a plus [+] followed by something that has to be added to the string. For example:

```
String firstPiece = "This is a ";
// this is ok:
String all = s + "String";
//if you call:
System.out.println(all);
//the output will be: This is a String

// this is not ok:
String allWrong = s "String";
//Even if you are putting one after the other the two strings, this is forbidden and is a Syntax error.
```

Comment: While this is true in the example he is giving, I think he gets the value of `s` from reading a text file, so this shouldn't be the error.... but I could be wrong.

Comment: String.replaceAll() takes a regex, and regex requires escaping of the '{' character.

Comment: replace all should work with curled brackets, so I don't think the problem is in the `String#replaceAll()` method. See also: [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). Here it says that problems can occur only with backslashes [\] and dollar signs [$]

Comment: If you escape the curly bracket you will get this error: `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \ )` because the brackets don't need to be escaped. for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844504/java-regex-to-match-curly-braces-invalid-escape-sequence

Comment: indeed, you have to double escape it ;) not single escape ;) your answer is ok, you comment is not so ok. I will edit my answer. And my comment too, my answer was focused on the escaping of double quote, I didn't pay attention to edit the code posted by the questioner. upvote for your answer

Comment: For the purposes of the example I've shown the and declared the string as s. However, I'm actually reading from a file and storing each line s.  Using s.replaceAll("\\{", " "); has no effect the { remain.

Comment: Try using `replaceAll("\\{|\\}", " ")` **OR** `replaceAll("[{}]", " ")`. Its working fine for me

Comment: I think the regex with both the brackets is better

Comment: @Gianmarco `replaceAll("\\{", "\\s");` This will replace `{` with `s`. Sorry for my previous comment and thats why I deleted it when I come to know my mistake.

Comment: I was trusting you and I edited my answer, even if it was strange to me the \s ;) now I am happy that I was not wrong ;)

Answer (score 19):

String.replaceAll() takes a regex, and regex requires escaping of the `'{'` character. So, replace:

```
s.replaceAll("{", " ");
```

with:

```
s.replaceAll("\\{", " ");
```

Note the double-escapes - one for the Java string, and one for the regex.

However, you don't really need a regex here since you're just matching a single character. So you could use the `replace` method instead:

```
s.replace("{", " "); // Replace string occurrences
s.replace('{', ' '); // Replace character occurrences
```

Or, use the regex version to replace both braces in one fell swoop:

```
s.replaceAll("[{}]", " ");
```

No escaping is needed here since the braces are inside a character class (`[]`).

Comment: Thanks to all for your suggestions. Thanks to Alex for answering the question... I can sleep now ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Just adding to the answer above:

If somebody is trying like below, this won't work:

```
 if(values.contains("\\{")){
        values = values.replaceAll("\\{", "");
    }
    if(values.contains("\\}")){
        values = values.replaceAll("\\}", "");
    }
```

Use below code if you are using contains():

```
if(values.contains("{")){
        values = values.replaceAll("\\{", "");
    }
    if(values.contains("}")){
        values = values.replaceAll("\\}", "");
    }
```